# How to configure SMTP email sender to not show AUTH PLAIN in logs

Tags: authentication, smtp

Good Day!
We are using an smpt proxy email server and this is just my first time using...
Just would like to ask if there are any configuration needed so that the AUTH PLAIN will not be shown in the logs? currently in the logs we can see something like

```
22:02:02.864961 send: 'AUTH PLAIN SAGAdaWQxLnVzZXIub2MxLi5hYWFhsddst
22:02:02.890036 reply: b'535 Authentication credentials invalid\r\n'
```

This is not Good because the AUTH PLAIN showing a decoded value, when this is decoded, it will show confidential information. Anyone familiar?

Thanks

Comment: Next time, provide at the very least what SMTP server you're using. How is anyone supposed to help with this as is?

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolve by setting the `debbug_level = 0`...

Comment: Did you mean to type `debug_level`?